# Обфускация кода java proguard

Tags: proguard, java

Мне нужно обфусцировать код с помощью proguard.
Добавил в мавен:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
<artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<proguardVersion>4.0betta1</proguardVersion>
<libs>
<lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
</libs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

При сборке mvn package выдает следующее:

```
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) net.sf.proguard:proguard:jar:4.0betta1

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.sf.proguard -DartifactId=proguard -Dversion=4.0betta1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.sf.proguard -DartifactId=proguard -Dversion=4.0betta1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
1) Product:Product:jar:1.0
2) net.sf.proguard:proguard:jar:4.0betta1

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
Product:Product:jar:1.0

from the specified remote repositories:
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Как сделать, чтобы обфусцировать при запуске mvn package?

Answer (score 2):

В блоке plugins в файле pom.xml

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.pro</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                </libs>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                <includeDependency>false</includeDependency>
                <proguardVersion>5.2.1</proguardVersion>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.1</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Файл proguard.pro для простого java-se приложения

```
-printmapping out/proguard/mapping.txt

-verbose

-optimizationpasses 3
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification

-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```